# Create a new line by pressing control + enter

Tags: vb.net

for some reason every time i try to press control + enter I get "send message" why is this?  I am pressing control so I should get create line..

```
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Debug.Print("create a new line")    
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Debug.Print("send message")
        End Sub
```

Comment: `If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this

```
If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
```